# Como leer un archivo txt por entrada estándar

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

Tengo un txt como este:

```
5
1
4
0 1 −1 7 0
−1 0 4 2 −1
−1 −1 0 −1 3 
−1 −1 1 0 5 
−1 −1 −1 −1 0
```

Necesito leer dicho txt por entrada estándar asi: `./miprograma < archivo.txt`

Los tres primeros numeros debo asignárselos a tres variables. (El primer numero indica la dimension de la matriz)

Luego el resto de numero asignarlos a una matriz.

Yo lo hago asi:

```
ifstream Archivo;
Archivo.open("aa.txt",ios::in);

Archivo >> dim;
Archivo >> Ini;
Archivo >> Fin;

matrizA = new int*[dim];

// Se le dan los valores a la matrizA
for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
    matrizA[i] = new int[dim];
    for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
        Archivo >>matrizA[i][j];
    }
}
Archivo.close();
```

Pero no se como es por entrada estándar (`./miprograma < archivo.txt`), Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pero no se como es por entrada estándar (./miprograma < archivo.txt),

Al ejecutar el programa de esa forma estás redireccionando la entrada estándar... en vez de leer del teclado pasará a leer del fichero.

Lo que sucede es que en ese momento tu *usuario* será el archivo y **únicamente** podrás leer el contenido del mismo.

En resumen... si redireccionan la entrada estándar tienes que leer usando `std::cin`:

```
int main()
{
  int dim, Ini, Fin;

  std::cin >> dim >> Ini >> Fin;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: admin... no se le dice fichero(.zip .rar) a un archivo de texto...

Comment: @RenatoA. En españa fichero y archivo son sinónimos